# Tomcat didn't deployed webapp files

Tags: java, tomcat

This is my first time to deploy Java web application using Tomcat.
I've created a Tapestry maven project, and I already get .war file to be deployed. I'm good to go.

But somehow, I keep getting HTTP 404
`The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.`

I'm investigating, and then I found that Tomcat didn't copied / deployed most of my webapp's files, only `META-INF` and `WEB-INF`.

I supposed this is why Tomcat couldn't find the `Index.tml`, which is actually exist. How to solve this problem? Tks.

Tomcat 8.5.29 `server.xml`
`<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">`

Comment: what steps you followed to create war file?

Comment: Right-click project, Run As -> Maven build (5)